# ReadFile function lpbuffer and bytes to read clarifcation

Tags: c++, winapi, buffer, readfile

I'm pretty new to this so any clarification would be appreciated. When using the function ReadFile, how does the type of the lpBuffer interact with the parameter of "number of bytes to read"?

For instance what if you had an unsigned short MyShort[5] as lpBuffer, and then you set bytes to read as 2.  Will all data be stored in MyShort[0]? Or would the first byte go into MyShort[0] and the second byte go into MyShort[1]?  What happens when you set bytes to read is increase say to 9? Will 16bits go into MyShort[0] and then 16 more into MyShort[1] etc...?

Thanks

Comment: The requested number of bytes is sequentially stored in the buffer. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467(v=vs.85).aspx) is also pretty clear about that.

Comment: The *lpBuffer* argument is of type `void*`. The `ReadFile` call cannot know the type you passed, so how should it respond to different types?

Comment: @IInspectable couldn't lpBuffer be a type char or an int?  I was just trying to figure out the interaction of 8 bits verses 16bits when 1 or 2 bytes are specified for number of bytes to read.

Comment: It doesn't matter, what type *your* buffer is. Once you pass it into `ReadFile`, all type information is lost. The [function signature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467.aspx) wants it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lpBuffer` is always treated as a pointer to an array of specified amount of bytes (`nNumberOfBytesToRead`). The amount of bytes actually read will be stored in the variable pointed to by `lpNumberOfBytesRead` parameter or as async (overlapped) result later. So in your case if you request to read 2 bytes it may either read two bytes storing both of them in `MyShort[0]`, or just a single byte stored in lower half of `MyShort[0]` or nothing at all. If you request to read 9 bytes then it will ready *up to* 9 bytes storing 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 1 bytes sequentially.